# How to change the channel in mac80211

Tags: c, linux-kernel, network-programming, wifi, linux-device-driver

I am trying to write a simple routine that will change the operating channel of the wireless device.

So far, I have:

```
/* These are function arguments */
struct ieee80211_local *local;
struct ieee80211_sub_if_data *sdata;

/* Declare a struct for the new channel */
struct cfg80211_chan_def new_channel;

/* Testing with 5765MHz */
new_channel.center_freq1 = 5765;
new_channel.center_freq2 = 0;
new_channel.chan = ieee80211_get_channel(sdata->local->hw.wiphy, 5765);
local->_oper_chandef = new_channel;

/* Reconfigure hardware */
ieee80211_hw_config(local, IEEE80211_CONF_CHANGE_CHANNEL);
```

However, I get plenty of Kernel level warnings due to invalid channel configuration, plus the channel does not change.

Hardware/software specifications:

- Fujitsu Lifebook S
- Atheros wireless card (ath9k)
- Linux kernel 3.14 (mptcp-0.89, to be more precise)